# VBA to automatically sort on update

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with three columns; A B and C. Values in column C are calculated using a formula, and I want to sort Z->A on column C, expanding the selection to the other two columns as well. My goal is to have the ranking automatically updated anytime a value in column C changes. I'm looking for someone who can write this for me, I know JS but not VBA and I'm having trouble figuring it out because it's not an easy one (at least for me). Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Columns("C").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

End Sub

```
=IFERROR(((ABS((((SUMIF(Orders!$B$1:$BJ$1, DATE((YEAR(TODAY())), (MONTH(TODAY())), ("<"&DAY(TODAY()))), Orders!B2:BJ2))-(SUMIF(Forecast!$B$1:$BJ$1, DATE((YEAR(TODAY())), (MONTH(TODAY())), ("<"&DAY(TODAY()))), Forecast!B2:BJ2)))/(SUMIF(Orders!$B$1:$BJ$1, DATE((YEAR(TODAY())), (MONTH(TODAY())), ("<"&DAY(TODAY()))), Orders!B2:BJ2))))*(SUMIF(Orders!$B$1:$BJ$1, DATE((YEAR(TODAY())), (MONTH(TODAY())), ("<"&DAY(TODAY()))), Orders!B2:BJ2)))/(SUMIF(Orders!$B$1:$BJ$1, DATE((YEAR(TODAY())), (MONTH(TODAY())), ("<"&DAY(TODAY()))), Orders!B2:BJ2))), 0)
```

Comment: *I'm looking for someone who can write this for me* - please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the most help on the site. In short, this isn't a "write my code for me site". But if you post the code you've tried and where it's failing, we'll help fix it up :) All that said, see the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event.

Comment: I updated what I have, but like I said, I don't really know the syntax of VBA and I've kind of pieced this together from a few different sources. The problem is I don't know how to expand the selection, and I'm not sure where to
actually store the macro itself, since it just changes when the page updates. Row 1 contains headers, hence the "C2".

Comment: thanks for updating trevor -> i have one question before I provide an answer. when you say **updated anytime a value in column C**. Is the formula in column C based on column A and B, only? Or does it derive it's values from other sheets? In short, we need to know what will cause the trigger since C is a formula it will not respond to the `Worksheet_Change` event by itself if it changes.

Comment: What cell or cells should trigger the event processing? Surely you do not want this to occur **every** time any cell's value changes.

Comment: Scott, the formula in column C does not reference column A or B (columns A and B are also values and not formulas), it's simply its position that matches up. Jeeped, only the cells in column C should trigger the change, and they will only change once per week (147 in total) so I don't think it would pose any kind of memory issue.

Comment: @trevor_bye - what drives a change in column C? You can use the worksheet_calculate event as well, but that may not be best suited for this either. As I said before, changes in formula cells **do not** trigger worksheet_change events. To be more clear, the line `If Target.Column = 1 Then` if your current code states that if a cell in column A is changed then sort then sort. Did you mean this?

Comment: A change in a calculated formula does not trigger the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. My answer below was predicated on your original trigger on changes to column A.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman sorry, I missed the point of your question. The formula in cell C2, for example, references two other sheets in the same book. I posted the formula in an additional edit to my question.

Comment: @trevor_bye - okay. One more question. Are the ranges referenced in in the Forecast and Orders sheet all values (or are they formulas as well)?

Comment: You cannot build a [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29) with `DATE((YEAR(TODAY())), (MONTH(TODAY())), ("<"&DAY(TODAY())))`. How does that even work?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the ranges referenced are formulas as well, that link to a different workbook. I think I see where this is going; our supply chain department is a chaotic rabbit hole of linked workbooks. I'm assuming this macro has to go through each reference until it eventually finds a value.

Comment: @trevor_bye no - the alternative is to have the sort happen each time the workbook is calculated. That is the easiest way to go here and should not take up too much time. It will resort on calculation no matter if the values in column C change or not. Is that okay?

Comment: Scott, yes that should work. @Jeeped how do you mean? I've tested it a few different ways and it seems to work, and it makes sense logically unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - The provided formula contains the [TODAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) which is volatile. This means that whenever **any** value in the entire workbook (or any other workbook in hte same application instance) is changed, a calculation event will occur on that worksheet. I don't think this is the correct avenue to proceed. I would try and fix that formula first and base a worksheet_change on changes to the cells that the formula references. Unfortunately, not enough information to fix the formula.

Comment: @Jeeped - I agree with you that the `worksheet_calculate` event is not ideal, but the formulas all are linked throughout other workbooks, so I don't see a way around it.

Comment: That DATE function is malformed. It results in a `#VALUE!` error. Best guess is that the whole date construction could be replaced with `Orders!$B$1:$BJ$1, "<"&TODAY(), ...`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - SOMETHING in that workbook has to change in order to recalculate. If the Worksheet_Change was moved to the originating worksheet it could still sort the calculated worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped - that was my thought originally, but the OP said the values in `Orders/Forecast!$B$1;$BJ$2` are formulas that link to other workbooks.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - <facepalm/>

Comment: @Jeeped I'm not getting a value error using the formula. I can't use your suggestion because because I need the criteria to be less than todays date, but only within the current month.

Comment: The criteria in the first SUMIFS is `DATE((YEAR(TODAY())), (MONTH(TODAY())), ("<"&DAY(TODAY())))`. That is **wrong**. Beyond the fact that it does not produce a valid date, if it was corrected it could very likely be replaced with `"<"&TODAY()`

Comment: Try it as `SUMIFS(B2:BJ2, Orders!B$1:BJ$1, ">"&EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1), Orders!B$1:BJ$1, "<"&TODAY())`. Essentially, sum from the first of this month to yesterday.

Comment: @Jeeped I went to lunch, realized how I was wrong, and I came up with the exact same formula. Thanks for the help, I'll try out the macro and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module in the `Microsoft Excel Objects` folder in the VBE.

This will sort by column C in the sheet (change name in code below to suit your actual sheet) anytime the workbook is recalculated. Obviously it will happen more times than needed, but it's the only way to ensure that it fires automatically.

If you have performance issues with this because of file size or amount of "recalcs" it's possible it can be tweaked a bit, or the design of the spreadsheet can be tweaked.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If sh.Name = "myABCSheet" or sh.Name = "Orders" or sh.Name = "Forecast"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("myABCSheet") 'change name as needed

    With ws

        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Sort

            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add ws.Range("C1:C" & lRow), 1, xlAscending
            End With

            .SetRange ws.Range("A1:C" & lRow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            Application.Calculation = xlManual
            .Apply
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End With

    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm fixing the formula and then I'll try the macro and let you know if it works.

Comment: changes in column C are triggering the macro, but I'm getting a Compile error: End If without block if. I'm trying to figure this syntax out but like I said, I don't work in VBA so it's tough.

Comment: @trevor_bye - sorry, i removed the extra `End If` that was there from a previous version of the answer I drew up.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. For some reason it attempts to update the sort on a constant basis, and it gets stuck on calculating: 73%. Any idea?

Comment: @trevor_bye - **sort on a constant basis** - that is the nature of the `Calculate Event`. It will run on *any* calculation - which may be a drawback. I edited the code to only fire if one of the 3 sheets are calculating (not sure if it will matter, since you have volatile formulas). I also added lines to turn off the calcs before sort, then turn them back on. That may (or may not) help. To be honest, this is a bit of a unique situation, but sorting affects calculation, so hopefully stopping them for a moment will help.

Comment: I think the key to this would be knowing if the Orders and/or Forecast worksheets contained **any** volatile functions. If not then their calculation event should be used to trigger the re-sort. Volatile functions include indirect, offset, today, now, rand, randbetween, some sub-functions of cell and info.